# Работа setTimeout в фоновом режиме?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я новичок, и задался проблемой написать таймер pomodoro с помощью js. Реализовал это с помощью setTimeout. Ниже кусок кода, который обеспечиват работу непосредственно таймера

```
function timer(){
    var dataBefore = new Date().getTime();
    if (timeNow > 0 && start === true){
        timeNow-=100;
        $('#time').html(convertForUser(timeNow));
        if (timeNow <= 0){
            counter+=1;
            if (counter % 2 === 1){
                timeNow = timeRest;
                $("#site-ico").attr("href", "/green.ico")
                $('.logo').html('<img src="/logo_rest.png" alt="logo"></img>');
            }
            else{
                timeNow = time;
                $("#site-ico").attr("href", "/red.ico")
                $('.logo').html('<img src="/logo_work.png" alt="logo"></img>');
            }

        }
        var diff = (new Date().getTime() - dataBefore);
    }

    else{
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(timer,(100-(diff*10)));
}
```

И все вроде адекватно работет, однако при потере фокуса, если во время работы приложения переключиться на другую вкладку, выполнение кода прекращается, таймер перестает работать. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

в общем суть в том, что браузер понижает или приостанавливает активность в неактивных вкладках, для решения такой проблемы используют Web Workers которые работают в отдельном от UI потоке.

Конкретно для вашей задачи есть готовая библиотека https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-timers